# I cant get my code to work. it keeps saying: IndexError: List index out of range

Tags: python

My code is using the lengths of lists to try and find a percentage of how many scores are over an entered number.It all makes sense but I think some of the code needs some editing because it comes up with that error code.How can I fix it???
Here is the code:

```
result = [("bob",7),("jeff",2),("harold",3)]
score = [7,2,3]
lower = []
higher = []
index2 = len(score)
indexy = int(index2)
index1 = 0
chosen = int(input("the number of marks you want the percentage to be displayed higher than:"))
for counter in score[indexy]:
    if score[index1] >= chosen:
        higher.append(score[index1])
    else:
        lower.append(score[index1])
    index1 = index1 + 1


original = indexy
new = len(higher)
decrease = int(original) - int(new)
finished1 = decrease/original
finished = finished1 * 100
finishedlow = original - finished
print(finished,"% of the students got over",chosen,"marks")
print(finishedlow,"% of the students got under",chosen,"marks")
```

Comment: If you could post the error and back trace it would save us needing to run it.

Comment: Index error IN WHAT LINE? Why do you keep that a secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice one thing:

```
>>>score = [7,2,3]
>>>len(score) = 3
```

but ,index of list start counting from 0, so

```
>>>score[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

fix your row 12 to:

```
...
for counter in score:
    if counter >= chosen:
        ...
```

if you really want to get the index and use them:

```
....
for index, number in enumerate(score):
    if score[index] >= chosen:
        ......
```

Answer (score -1):

`index2` is an int, so no need to convert it to `indexy`. Indizes in Python are counted from 0, so the highest index is `len(list)-1`.
You have a `counter`, so why use `index1` in for-loop? You cannot iterate over a number `score[indexy]`.

```
results = [("bob",7),("jeff",2),("harold",3)]

chosen = int(input("the number of marks you want the percentage to be displayed higher than:"))
higher = sum(score >= chosen for name, score in results)

finished = higher / len(results)
finishedlow = 1 - finished
print("{0:.0%} of the students got over {1} marks".format(finished, chosen))
print("{0:.0%} of the students got under {1} marks".format(finishedlow, chosen))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is in Line 9:    `for counter in score[indexy]:`

`counter` should iterate through a list not through an `int` and even that you are referring to a value that is out of index range of your list:

1 - Remember indexing should be from 0 to (len(list)-0).

2 - You cannot iterate through a fixed value of int.

So, you should change Line 9 to :

`for counter in score`

But I'm not sure of the result you will get from your code, you need to check out your code logic.

There is a lot to optimize in your code.